# How do I solve "Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing" error?

Tags: apt, software-installation

I'm trying to install phpMyAdmin using `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` but encountering this error

```
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main mysql-common all 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 194.169.254.10 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main mysql-common all 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libmysqlclient18 i386 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main mysql-client-core-5.5 i386 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main mysql-client-5.5 i386 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main mysql-client all 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-common_5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/libmysqlclient18_5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-client-core-5.5_5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-client_5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

What could be the issue here? How do I solve it?

Comment: My '/etc/apt/source.list' file does not have a line containing 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/' . What shoul I do?
What does that line suggest?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then retry.

Comment: I have tried this multiple times still issue exists. I am not able to install Filezilla on my Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 19):

If `sudo apt-get update` is also not working then follow the steps below:-

1. Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.
2. Check the word after `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` in the `sources.list` file, let the word be `xyz`
3. Go to the address `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` and then click on dists. Now check whether `xyz` is present at this path. If it is not present, then replace `xyz` with the element which is present in 'dists' such as:- saucy, lucid, trusty etc.
4. Now run `sudo apt-get update` command.

Comment: +1. One note though: if this happens, it means that your linux is no longer supported, in which case it might make sense to switch to a newer version.

Comment: this is indeed a better response than the accepted one. See ntg's comment tho

Comment: This is a great answer; I am running   18.04 and my sources list was archive.ubuntu.com bionic; changed it to security.ubuntu.com; now it works perfectly.

Comment: In my case, instead of http://security.ubuntu.com/, http://in.security.ubuntu.com/ like url were present. I removed `in` prefix (I know, at some point it was working with `in`, later Ubuntu guys might have changed the mind). Anyway, visiting the url in browser as you mentioned, helped me to reach to this solution.

Comment: You are awesome

Comment: Shouldn't abrupt alteration of the distro's `sources.list` file respective codename result in dependency hell? I mean Ubuntu's upstream software delay exists for a reason.

Answer (score 3):

There is a command to point source urls in olds releases .

a goog explanation in this github gist :

https://gist.github.com/dergachev/f5da514802fcbbb441a1

Comment: You don't need to go to Github for that, we have one right here: http://askubuntu.com/q/91815/158442. Even so, this isn't applicable here, since OP is using 12.04 and 12.04 is still supported.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` to `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then run `apt-get update`

(You can check if your particular distro is there by accessing the http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ in your browser and then select /dists, but if it is not on security.ubuntu.com, it should be on old-releases

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to main server under software and updates in system settings. Then use sudo apt-get update and then try installing. I had a same issue while installing synaptic package manager.

Comment: Before you try changing to main server visit the URL that is giving the `404 Not Found` message in a web browser to check if it is down.