# `apt-get install` tries to fetch the wrong file

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-sources

I am trying to install curl using

```
apt-get install curl
```

But it is producing errors:

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 curl amd64 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.12
  404  Not Found
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 curl amd64 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.12
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.47.0-1ubuntu2.12_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
```

**My Thoughts:**

I referred to [this article](https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-ubuntudebian-apt-get-404-not-found-package-repository-errors-saucy-raring-quantal-oneiric-natty/), then I realized that since my version 16.04 LTS, so it's still supported, and it's not the problem.

I also read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/416930/), but both answers can't be applied to my case (`apt-get update` fails and `xenial-security` is present in `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/`).

Next, I visited the URL http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl, and I figured out that ***curl_7.47.0-1ubuntu2.13_amd64.deb*** is there instead of ***curl_7.47.0-1ubuntu2.12_amd64.deb***, which is being requested by `apt-get`. As a result, I deduce that `apt-get` should ask for `2.13` rather than `2.12`, hence the title.

However, I am kind of stuck here. I am not sure what I should do next to resolve this issue, and I appreciate any advice.

**Output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`**

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

**Output of `apt-get update`**

```
Hit:1 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]                  
Get:3 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]                                                               
Hit:4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                      
Get:5 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [957 kB]                                
Get:6 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [824 kB]                          
Get:7 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en [381 kB]                   
Ign:8 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                            
Ign:9 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                
Get:10 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [748 kB]                                      
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]                                                     
Get:12 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [685 kB]                          
Get:13 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en [311 kB]                         
Ign:14 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                    
Ign:15 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:16 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [16.7 kB]                                               
Get:17 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [15.8 kB]                   
Ign:18 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                     
Ign:8 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                         
Ign:9 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons     
Ign:14 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:15 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                 
Ign:18 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                            
Ign:19 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:20 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                            
Ign:8 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                   
Get:9 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [309 kB]
Err:9 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                  
  Hash Sum mismatch
Ign:14 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata          
Ign:18 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                            
Ign:19 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                
Ign:20 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                            
Ign:19 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                
Ign:20 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:19 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7280 B]
Err:19 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  Hash Sum mismatch
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [648 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages [535 kB]
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Translation-en [264 kB]
Ign:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons    
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages [435 kB]
Get:27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages [378 kB]                                                    
Get:28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Translation-en [176 kB]                                                   
Ign:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                     
Ign:30 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                        
Ign:31 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                   
Ign:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                         
Ign:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                            
Ign:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                     
Ign:30 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                        
Ign:31 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                   
Ign:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                         
Err:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                            
  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Ign:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                     
Ign:30 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                        
Ign:31 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                   
Ign:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                         
Fetched 5766 kB in 14s (394 kB/s)                                                                                                           
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/tw.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.xz - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to fetch http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Failed to fetch http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/tw.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_universe_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to fetch http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Failed to fetch http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/tw.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_universe_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.xz - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Please, edit the question to post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: The `sudo apt update` bit is pretty important to the system:  "update" tells the system what versions of what programs are available - since you can't run update, your installation does not know the correct version.  Or many other important things, like security updates.  Please append your question with the output of `sudo apt update` and this site will try to help you fix that problem, which will make the problem you wrote about, go away.

Comment: @Olimjon thank you for the suggestion, question edited.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I've appended the output, thank you.

Comment: @DavidChen  Thank you!  Did you use `sudo` when you ran the command?

Comment: @CharlesGreen yes, I am in a root shell via `sudo su`. Besides, I successfully `apt-get update` by referring to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917603/sudo-apt-get-update-failing-could-not-open-list-file-due-to-permission-deni), hence the original problem is also solved. Thank you for pointing out how important `apt-get update` is, and I think I will update the question to emphasize this.

Comment: @DavidChen No problem with the pointing-out bit.  Have you already tried deleting the lists directory as mentioned in the question that you referenced?  [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error) talks about the same solution for the hash-sum mismatch.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Yes. I run `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*`, and then `sudo apt-get update` can be executed successfully.

Comment: Great!  Then you should be able to both `sudo apt update` to bring your system up to date, and `sudo apt install curl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt-get update` solves this issue as pointed out by Charles's comment. In my particular case, by referring to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917603/sudo-apt-get-update-failing-could-not-open-list-file-due-to-permission-deni), running `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*` makes `sudo apt-get update` be executed successfully.